# gnuplot cannot zoom on Mac Sierra

Tags: x11, osx, gnuplot

A simple example such as

```
gnuplot --persist -e 'plot sin(x)'
```

I cannot zoom with or without mouse, or with the trackpad. I've checked/unchecked "emulate three button mouse" button too, I've plotted with and without --persis. I can get the crosshair by pressing the cmd button but after that I cannot zoom or anything special. How to fix this?

Gnuplot version=5

Comment: Same question on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846976/xquartz-gnuplot-mac-sierra-trackpad-issue).

Comment: You deserve an award